# como filtrar dados de uma tabela

Tags: laravel

Tenho uma tabela `estagiario` que esta relacionada com uma tabela `areas`, e a tabela `areas` por sua vez esta relacionada com a tabela `departamento`.

Eu consigo até listar todos os estagiários usado a seguinte função:

```
public function index(){
        $data = date("Y-m-d");
        $terminados = Estagiario::whereDate('fim_estagio', '<=', $data)->paginate(6);       
        return view('estagiarios.terminado',compact('terminados'));
    }
```

E estou a ter problemas de ter os estagiários que estão associados a um certo departamento.

```
public function search(Request $request){
        $search=$request->get('Departamento');
        $data = date("Y-m-d");
        $terminados =Estagiario::whereDate('fim_estagio', '<=', $data)
                            ->where('areas.departamento.name','=', $search)
                            ->paginate(6);
    return view('estagiarios.terminado',compact('terminados'));
    }
```

Comment: Por favor apresente o código formatado.

Answer (score 0):

Olá.

Creio que faltou especificar os relacionamentos entre as tabelas em sua consulta.

Pelo código que você apresentou, você está filtrando por um parâmetro que está na terceira entidade mas faltou especificar os relacionamentos entre elas na consulta.

Um exemplo para uma consulta assim seria algo parecido com o código abaixo:

```
public function search(Request $request){
    $search=$request->get('Departamento');
    $data = date("Y-m-d");
    $terminados =Estagiario::whereDate('fim_estagio', '<=', $data)
                        ->join('areas', 'areas.id', '=', 'estagiario.id')
                        ->join('departamento', 'departamento.id', '=', 'areas.id')
                        ->where('departamento.name','=', $search)
                        ->paginate(6);
return view('estagiarios.terminado',compact('terminados'));
```

}

[Documentação do Laravel aqui 'JOIN'](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins)